# Latitude and Longitude conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gps

I need to convert a latitude in ddmm.mmmmm (minutes in 4 decimal places) to ddmm.mmmmmm (minutes in 5 decimal places) format. Is there any good formula to convert this ?

Comment: can you give more information? with such a small amount of information advice above seems valid :)

Comment: Actually I got latitude & logitude data from GPS device in ddmm.mmmm format for ex: 3323.8733. Now I need to store this data in ddmm.mmmmm format i.e 3323.87333 format (i.e minutes in 5 decimal places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

We need to follow these steps for this conversion
1. Convert value in ddmm.mmmm format to dd.ddddddd by using the following  formula
   dd.ddddddd =  dd + ( mm.mmmm / 60 )

1. convert back 
   ddmm.mmmmm =  concat(dd, (.dddddd * 60))

   Example:

   To convert 3323.8733 from ddmm.mmmm format

   1. convert to degrees (dd.dddd) format
      33 +  (23.8733 / 60 ) = 33.397888333333334
   2. convert back to ddmm.mmmmm format
      multiply decimal part by 60  i.e 0.397888333333334 * 60 => 23.87330000000004
      append with degree 
      3323.87330000000004

      As we need ddmm.mmmmm we can round of 5 decimal places i.e 3323.87330

Answer (score 0):

Sans other information I would recommend following mkk's advice.

If you want to convert "ddmm.mmmmm" (4 decimal places) to "ddmm.mmmmm" (5 decimal places), you should probably just add a zero to the end.

Other methods may appear to give a more satisfactory result by placing a non-zero value in the fifth decimal place. But they *cannot add more information* than was present in the original number. There is, however, the potential to lose information through [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) in mathematical calculations.